# How do I find the indefinite integral of $\int_0^{\pi} (4\sin x-3\cos x) dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\pi} (4\sin x-3\cos x) dx 
=[- 4\cos x-3\sin x+c]_0^\pi$$

$$=-4\cos(\pi)+c-(-4\cos(0)+c) - (3\sin(\pi)+c - ( 3\sin(0)-c))$$
$$= 0+c+4(1)-c -3(0) - 3(0)-c =4$$

Can someone show me how to do this question properly? The answer I obtained was $4$ after plugging in the upper and lower bound values however the textbook says it is $8$.

Thank you!

Comment: How *exactly* did you obtain the result $7$?

Comment: The integral is a definite one and it is a real number. It cannot be equal to a function of $x$. I know what you mean but have to phrase it precisely.

Comment: What you probably mean is $[- 4\cos x-3\sin x+c]_{x=0}^{x=\pi}$, but I really do not see how you could get $7$ as the result.

Comment: Please show your work! Otherwise we don't know where you made a mistake.

Comment: @AmaanM I added in my work.

Comment: @MartinR, I actually got 4 but its still not right. I put in the work I did, could you take a look at it?

Comment: $\cos(\pi)=-1\neq 0$

Comment: If you think about it, $\sin$ and $\cos$ cannot both be $0$ at $\pi$ since $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ must hold for all real $x$.

Comment: As Gary pointed out, the issue is you put $\cos(\pi) = 0$, when you should have $\cos(\pi) = -1$. One more note, you can substitute in the two endpoints into the whole expression at once (and not incorporate $+c$ multiple times): $[-4\cos(x)-3\sin(x)+c]_0^{\pi} = [-4\cos(\pi)-3\sin(\pi)+c]-[-4\cos(0)-3\sin(0)+c]$. That makes it just a bit tidier and easier to track what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the integral, since we are subtracting two functions, we can separate these two to make the integral more readable.
$$\int_0^{\pi} 4 \sin(x) - 3\cos(x) dx = \int_0^{\pi}4\sin(x)dx - \int_0^{\pi} 3\cos(x)dx$$

Now we will integrate each integral. Below is the first part:
$$\int_0^{\pi}4\sin(x)dx = -4(\cos(x))\big|_0^\pi
\\ =-4(\cos(\pi) - \cos(0)) \\
=-4(-1-1)\\
=8.$$
Now the other:
$$\int_0^{\pi}3\cos(x)dx = 3(\sin(x)) \big|_0^\pi
\\
=3(\sin(\pi) - \sin(0)) \\
3 (0-0) \\
=0$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^{\pi} 4 \sin(x) - 3\cos(x) dx = 8 - 0 = \boxed{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an indefinite integral. It has limits, which means that it's a definite integral, which means that you don't need to include the +C part; it cancels out. As Michael said, you evaluated $\cos(\pi)$ incorrectly. As far as a broader strategy, consulting a unit circle may help. If you have open notes tests, bring one with you; if not, draw one on scratch paper.